# Run task in certain time located in conf file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, configuration, scheduled-tasks

I need run some task in specific time
but this time located in conf file.

time in it can changed.
I doesn't want reload each time server to read time on it

I can use @Schedule read conf file and run task if it need
but maybe is more elegant solution.

thanks

Comment: Try Quartz library: http://quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: If you have resource that you need to change often, maybe the conf file is not the best solution to store it...